# Short error when data is retrieved from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I am retrieving a document from Firebase and try to display this data in my application.
The user clicked on an item and is forwarded to this page here. At the same time the information about the selected item is forwarded with the following code:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SearchResult(item.abc)));
```

The result of the following code is OK and the correct name is displayed. But while loading this error appears briefly:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SearchResult(dirty, state: 
_SearchResultState#9a2f6):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("Name")
```

A short moment later the name is displayed in my application. I think this is a problem with loading the data from Firebase. How can I solve this?
This is my code:

```
class SearchResult extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;
  SearchResult(this.data);

  @override
  _SearchResultState createState() => _SearchResultState();
}

class _SearchResultState extends State<SearchResult>  {
  dynamic data_snap;

Future<dynamic> getData() async{
print(widget.data);
final DocumentReference document = Firestore.instance.collection("Players").document(widget.data);
await document.get().then<dynamic>(( DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async{
  setState(() {
    data_snap =snapshot.data;
  });
});
}
  
@override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getData();
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Player'),
  ),
  body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(data_snap['Name']),
              ),
            )
          ]
      )
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share code, where you tried accessing value of key `Name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening because when the build method runs the application might still be fetching the data you should control this and add a progress indicator in that case

Try something like this:

```
class _SearchResultState extends State<SearchResult>  {
dynamic data_snap;
bool _loading = false;

Future<dynamic> getData() async{
print(widget.data);
    final DocumentReference document = 
Firestore.instance.collection("Players").document(widget.data);
       _loading = true;
    await document.get().then<dynamic>(( DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async{
      setState(() {
        data_snap =snapshot.data;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
    }
```

And then in your build method do the following:

```
  child: _loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : 
         ListTile(
            title: Text(data_snap['Name']),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. But now I get the following error when I use this in other parts of my code: type 'CircularProgressIndicator' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' How can I solve this?

Comment: You might be using the CircularProgressIndicator as a children for Column or Row widgets, try [ CircularProgressIndicator() ] as an array